# got error when run mahout cat ponut.csv

Tags: mahout

when i run 
`mahout cat ponut.csv`
got this error

> Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
>   MAHOUT-JOB: /Users/shawn/Code/mahout/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.9-job.jar
>   Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: donut.csv (No such file or directory)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
>       at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TrainLogistic.open(TrainLogistic.java:315)
>       at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.PrintResourceOrFile.main(PrintResourceOrFile.java:36)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:145)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:153)
>       at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

Mahout version is 0.9.
I run mvn install form source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name is donut.csv :)
And it is present at-

```
examples/src/main/resources/donut.csv
```

You can try :

```
bin/mahout cat examples/src/main/resources/donut.csv
```